# Google GAE json output producing duplicate objects (Closed) was an Api issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gson

I have a java app that I have deployed on GAE.  I am using Gson for serializing and deserializing.  I am also using joda-time 2.4.

When I run the app on eclipse as a java application... the json output is as shown below:  (The json is simplified)

---

```
{
"_id": "gasqi2ceL3caLHcMc",
"resultHeader": {
    "enterprise": "ABC Corp"
},
"craneScheduleList": [
    {
        "craneId": "crane3",
        "scheduleMemberList": [
            {
                "scheduleStartTimeUTC": "2015-10-04T13:00:00.000Z",
                "scheduleEndTimeUTC": "2015-10-04T13:18:00.000Z",
                "status": "OPERATIONAL",
                "load": {
                    "loadId": "00004",
                    "loadSequenceNumber": 1,
                    "assetsInLoadList": [
                        {
                            "assetId": "10128"
                        },
                        {
                            "assetId": "10135"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "scheduleStartTimeUTC": "2015-10-04T13:18:00.000Z",
                "scheduleEndTimeUTC": "2015-10-04T13:27:00.000Z",
                "status": "OPERATIONAL",
                "load": {
                    "loadId": "00002_1",
                    "loadSequenceNumber": 2,
                    "assetsInLoadList": [
                        {
                            "assetId": "10150"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

---

When I run the same data on GAE engine.. the output show 3 duplicates of each the objects as shown below:

---

```
{
"_id": "gasqi2ceL3caLHcMc",
"resultHeader": {
    "enterprise": "ABC Corp"
},
"craneScheduleList": [
    {
        "craneId": "crane3",
        "scheduleMemberList": [
            {
                "scheduleStartTimeUTC": "2015-10-04T08:00:00.000Z",
                "scheduleEndTimeUTC": "2015-10-04T08:18:00.000Z",
                "status": "OPERATIONAL",
                "load": {
                    "loadId": "00004",
                    "loadSequenceNumber": 1,
                    "assetsInLoadList": [
                        {
                            "assetId": "10128"
                        },
                        {
                            "assetId": "10135"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "scheduleStartTimeUTC": "2015-10-04T08:00:00.000Z",
                "scheduleEndTimeUTC": "2015-10-04T08:18:00.000Z",
                "status": "OPERATIONAL",
                "load": {
                    "loadId": "00004",
                    "assetsInLoadList": [
                        {
                            "assetId": "10128"
                        },
                        {
                            "assetId": "10135"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "scheduleStartTimeUTC": "2015-10-04T08:00:00.000Z",
                "scheduleEndTimeUTC": "2015-10-04T08:18:00.000Z",
                "status": "OPERATIONAL",
                "load": {
                    "loadId": "00004",
                    "loadSequenceNumber": 1,
                    "assetsInLoadList": [
                        {
                            "assetId": "10128"
                        },
                        {
                            "assetId": "10135"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

---

I am not sure why the duplicate objects are created when the app is run on GAE.  Wanted to get some input if the problem exists with my expectation or am I missing something here.

Comment: Can you show us how you use Gson and what data you serialize / deserialize?

Comment: Well it looks like you're adding the same reference of an object to the list multiple times and then modify the actual data, probably by accident. Also note that your scheduleMemberList does not contain exact clones as the loadSequenceNumber attribute does not exist in the second array element. I recommend you make sure you're not reusing objects.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I found the problem and it seemed to work.  Previously I  had the Engine Object Instance as a field of the API itself.   It seemed to retain the previous values when the api is called again.   When I moved the Engine new Object Instance inside the Post Method, it started to work as a New Engine object was created everytime when the Post Method was run.